# How to find whether a given matrix is symmetric, idempotent, or orthogonal?

Tags: self-study, matrix

Let $x$ be a non-zero column vector and 
$$
P= ( xx^\intercal)/(x^\intercal x) 
$$
be an $n\times n$ matrix where $n>1$. Then what is the nature of matrix $P$?
(here $x^\intercal$ denotes transpose of $x$)

Comment: Could you define the nature of a matrix?

Comment: To find out whether P is symmetric, idempotent or orthogonal

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried taking transpose on both sides but I got stuck.

Comment: Use $ (xx^\prime)^\prime = (x^\prime)^\prime x^\prime = xx^\prime.$

Comment: Here's another hint: Extend $x$ to an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then the representation of $P$ in this basis consists of $n^2-1$ zeros with a $1$ in the upper left corner.  The answers to all your questions are now immediate upon inspecting $P$.

Comment: You got a very nice answer and some hints. Can I kindly suggest that you click on "accept" if you feel like the problem is solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking the symmetry of this matrix is pretty straightforward. Use the property $(xy^T)^T = yx^T$ and the fact that $x^Tx$ is a scalar.

$P^T = \left(\frac{xx^T}{x^Tx}\right)^T = \frac{(xx^T)^T}{x^Tx} = \frac{(x^T)^T x^T}{x^Tx} = \frac{xx^T}{x^Tx} =  P.$

Checking idempotence of the matrix also relies on the fact the $x^Tx$ is a scalar.

$PP = \frac{xx^T}{x^Tx}\frac{xx^T}{x^Tx} = \frac{xx^Txx^T}{(x^Tx)(x^Tx)} = \frac{x(x^Tx)x^T}{(x^Tx)^2} = \frac{x^Tx}{x^Tx}\frac{xx^T}{x^Tx} = \frac{xx^T}{x^Tx} = P.$

Checking orthogonality is just a matter of showing that $PP^T = P^TP = I$. I claim that this follows from the fact that the matrix is both symmetric and idempotent. Can you see why that is true?